# How to handle non-divisible numbers

Tags: types, division

I can't find any question or library that handles this issue. I assume it is because I'm not too much involved in math programming.

So basically here is my problem. Let's say I have three users, each user in my system has a variable with his balance:

```
var balance_1 = 1;

var balance_2 = 1;

var balance_3 = 1;
```

Let's say I want my system to be flexible and enable users to send parts of their balance to other users. For example, user 1 sends 1/3 of his balance to user 2. User 3 sends 2/3 of his balance to user 2.

```
balance_1 = 1 - 1/3

balance_2 = 1 + 1/3 + 2/3 = 2

balance_3 = 1 - 2/3
```

So where is the problem? Well the problem is, if I'm using floating numbers (or whatever integer like precision), I'll always end up with balance_3 = 1.999~ However, that's not reality (or the result I'm looking for). I want balance_3 to be 2.

So basically I'm looking for some kind of type that allows me to store values such as "1/3" on their full value instead of their approximation.

Any suggestions on where I should look?

PS: No specific language. I'm looking to see how developers handle this situation generally speaking.

Comment: You can store 1/5, because it's precision is limited, but the number 1/3 can't be stored, because the '3' after the 0 in 0.33333... goes forever, while the memory size is limited.

Comment: @BiteBytes: You could represent it quite compactly as the pair (1,3).

Comment: one trick is you use a structure with two fields, denominator and nomenator, and write the appropriate interface to handle it.

Comment: @ScottHunter indeed, that's what I was about to say.

Comment: The equivalent of this question has been asked (and answered) dozens of times here. Search for *is floating point math broken*.

Comment: @BiteBytes Indeed, that was an oversight. However, I think the question title should be changed as it is not about non-divisible numbers but rather for numbers where the reminder is of infinite value;

Comment: @OmarAbid: Can you provide an example of a "remainder of infinite value"?

Comment: @ScottHunter Maybe I didn't explain myself clearly. For example, 1/3 has an infinite decimal after 0. 0,33333...

Answer (score 1):

Scheme has a `rational` type to represent rational numbers, so you might want to look at how that is implemented.